# Is it a good practice to add thesis statement to non-academic writing?

Tags: style, creative-writing, academic-writing

Having thesis statement in the intro; what would you think is it a good practice to have in non-academic writing

Thanks

Comment: why would you have a thesis statement in non-academic writing? What *are* you writing? an essay? a memo? a report? a blog post? We need more context.

Comment: Its a market research report for 3 different industries.

Comment: You only have one shot to grab a reader...so make it good.

Answer (score 1):

If you're writing a research report, then yes, you should have "here is the thing we are studying" or "this is the question we are trying to answer" in the introduction of the report. Otherwise the reader won't know what you're reporting on. I don't know if you'd call that a thesis per se.

Answer (score 0):

If it serves the story then I don't see a problem. But it must be entertaining - be interesting for the reader and provoke imagination; it should catch the reader's attention - to work as a hook. Every intro should be a representation to the whole literary work in a way. It should not be long to become annoying (maybe filter only the interesting parts). And the statement should be correlated to what you want to convey with your writing. It might be a good idea to be something controversial and to raise questions. Also it should fit the rhythm of the rest of the discourse and suit the mood.
If I had to place such a thesis as an intro I'd leave a lot of information blanks which to be answered/revealed later.
And last, remember that all the points above might be valid or invalid for your case.